# Upload StorageFile to a PHP File

Tags: c#, php, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have been trying to upload a StorageFile (mostly image files) to a PHP File so that it can save into the server.

## ViewModel.cs

```
public async Task<bool> uploadFile(StorageFile file)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpMultipartFormDataContent form = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                using (IInputStream fileStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
                {
                    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(fileStream);
                    form.Add(streamContent, "file", file.Name);

                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("localhost/uploadFile.php")))
                        {
                            request.Content = form;
                            HttpResponseMessage response =  await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
                            Debug.WriteLine("\nRequest: " + request.ToString());
                            Debug.WriteLine("\n\nResponse: " + response.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
       return false;
   }
}
```

## uploadFile.php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadedFile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)){
    echo 'File upload success!';
} else {
    echo 'Possible file upload attack!';
}
?>
```

The problem is when I try to upload a file, it threw me an error `The object has been closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0X80000013)` and `Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.ni.dll`.. I don't understand, I do the file uploading inside the `using` statement, how can it is disposed? Am I doing something wrong?

The debug shows me this

> Request: Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost/uploadFile.php', Content: Windows.Web.Http.HttpMultipartFormDataContent, TransportInformation: ServerCertificate: '', ServerCertificateErrorSeverity: None, ServerCertificateErrors: {}, ServerIntermediateCertificates:{}, Headers:{  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate }{ Content-Length: 27749, Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=9955f08b-e82d-428b-82e1-3197e5011ccd }
>
> Response: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 2, Content: Windows.Web.Http.HttpStreamContent, Headers:{Connection: Keep-Alive, Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, Date: Sun, 06 Nov 2016 04:02:40 GMT}{ Content-Length: 28, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects. Simply to say, it helps you to execute the [`Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So your code is equal to:

```
 HttpMultipartFormDataContent form = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();               
 IInputStream fileStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
 HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(fileStream);
 form.Add(streamContent, "file", file.Name);    
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();             
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9096/hello.php"));
 request.Content = form;      
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
 Debug.WriteLine("\nRequest: " + request.ToString());
 Debug.WriteLine("\n\nResponse: " + response.ToString());
 request.Dispose();
 client.Dispose();
 fileStream.Dispose();
 form.Dispose();
```

You will got the exception at `form.Dispose();` code line. The reason is that [HttpMultipartFormDataContent.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279599.aspx)  method doesn't need dispose. In my opinion, it is not the unmanaged resource which doesn't need dispose, other methods of `HttpMultipartFormDataContent` class like [`ReadAsBufferAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpmultipartformdatacontent.readasbufferasync.aspx) may need dispose.

Update your code as follows which will not throw the `closed` exception:

```
HttpMultipartFormDataContent form = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
using (IInputStream fileStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(fileStream);
    form.Add(streamContent, "file", file.Name);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9096/hello.php")))
        {
            request.Content = form;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
            Debug.WriteLine("\nRequest: " + request.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("\n\nResponse: " + response.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```